# Get ContentType of documentSet using Javascript(CSOM)

Tags: sharepoint

How can i access all the contenttypes for a particular docset using javascript

Using server model we can achieve it by

```js
var ctIds = ds.ContentTypeTemplate.AllowedContentTypes;


 //1
 foreach (SPContentTypeId ctId in ctIds)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(ctId); //print Content Type Id
 }
```

But how to achieve this in CSOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a rest api call on that said list:

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: "_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('LIST NAME')/items?$select=Title,ContentTypeId",
type: "GET",
cache: false,
headers: {
    "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
},
success: function(data) {
    // CT in data.d.ContentTypes.results
},
error: function() {

   }});
```

This will return all CT that are associated with this document set list.

Comment: Thanks dotsa .. I will try this and let you know

Comment: Hi dotsa I am getting all the contentypes for the list but i need to get the CT for a particular document set .